# SQL Denormalization, Combining table columns to another table columns

Tags: mysql, denormalization

I'm having trouble joining together the tables in my database, I want to display it in a specific order heres the example.

Table: `product`

```
product_id product_price product_qty
1          5.25          100
```

Table: `product_detail`

```
product_id product_name product_generic_name
1          Alcohol      Isoprophyl Alcohol
```

And I want the RESULT of the JOINING to be

```
product_id product_name product_generic_name product_price product_qty
1          Alcohol      Isoprophyl Alchohol  5.25          100
```

My failed code was:

```
SELECT `product_detail`.`product_name`,`product_detail`.`product_name`,`product_detail`.`product_generic_name` 
FROM `product_detail`
UNION
SELECT * FROM `product`
```

But the result is not what I need, it doesnt add columns only the rows.
Please give me advice on how to solve this problem,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.product_id,
       product_name ,
       product_detail,
       product_generic_name ,
       product_price, 
       product_qty
FROM product as p
       inner join product_detail as pd on p.id = pd.id
```

You may want to read up on a few mysql tutorials on how to join tables as this is probably as simple as it gets [MySQL Reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Based on your comments here is another option to try:

```
Select * from
         (SELECT p.product_id,
                 product_name ,
                 product_detail,
                 product_generic_name ,
                 product_price, 
                 product_qty
         FROM product as p) as newTable
```

Or alternatively you could try temporary tables if you want something else.

```
create temporary table new_table
SELECT p.product_id,
                 product_name ,
                 product_detail,
                 product_generic_name ,
                 product_price, 
                 product_qty
         FROM product as p
```

Then in the same script or however your calling it you could try:

select * from new_table

Comment: Thank you Mr. dreza its really a big help!

Comment: Quick question though, whats gonna be the new name of the table?
Is it table `p`?

Comment: @anoldgangstah The result will be a result set and not a table entity as such so it won't have a name directly.  Why would you need a table name?

Comment: I need a table name so that if I add a product it will automatically update, As i applied that code it seems that the new product isnt displaying at all. But if I SELECT `product` it will populate automatically, How do I do that in this new unknown table?

Comment: @anoldgangstah  I'm slightly confused.  You do not mention doing any adding in your question?  Are you trying to do an insert or update on a joined table?

Comment: Okay let me simplify it, I want to combine those two tables into one and place it to another table that I wish to declare. Is it possible?

Comment: @anoldgangstah  That's not simplified. That's just giving more information to your problem.  You may want to consider adding this kind of stuff to your question as it will help people to help you.

Comment: Okay dreza never mind I solved my problem, turns out that I don't need a new table i just need to loop properly to the database so I can display the data into the the webpage. Thanks for the help btw.

Godbless

Comment: The examples that you've presented worked well too. I can now populate data properly. And I can use it for future references thanks very much!

Comment: @anoldgangstah np.  don't forget to upvote etc if this helped :)

Comment: I can't do that right now, I still need 15 rep. Anyways I've voted it as the correct answer!